# How can I make sure users privacy?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

I have used Gmail API and other similar multiple times for building chatbots, mobile apps and webapps in Hackathons.

One particular trend I have seen is that people are reluctant to even try it, mostly because of privacy concerns. Most of them don't even know that they can remove third-party apps access under their user tab immediately after trying it. When given the option to self-host (say deploy to Heroku) they actively use the app. One problem is that they have to create app, configure client_id, client_secret etc.

So is there a way by which they don't have to do any configurations but all their credentials like access_token, refresh_token stay on their own server, or any other way by which they make sure their data is safe.

Comment: They just need to be auth server (issue token and validate token), whenever use your app, you validate against their auth server as provider. How that sounds?

Comment: I didn't get. Can you elaborate?

Comment: After editing your question, I misunderstood earlier. People opt for the private cloud, hosted apps completely based on the privacy of data and security concerns. I guess there is no way if they dont want to exchange a single piece of info between your app and their token provider.

Comment: @chenrui is there any harm in keeping client_id, client_secret public, given that you must self host?

Comment: @chenrui I mean even if client_secret is public, hacker would need access_token to access data. Am I missing something?

Comment: client_id, client_secret is just shared between two servers. With networking protection like (CIDR, IP whitelist and certificate), you can disable the third party access.